# Cant get token from janrain

Tags: php, callback, token, janrain, rpx

I set up the authentication window, according to the introduction janrain, but as the callback come, there is no token. What could be the problem?

Here is the magic code:

...

```
$rpxApiKey = '95c8d032db3db656e7716749552ff12c82f7108f';  

if(isset($_POST['token'])) { 

echo "hello";

  /* STEP 1: Extract token POST parameter */
  $token = $_POST['token'];
```

...

but hello is not appearing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to https://rpxnow.com/ and login.
2. Go to "Deployment" -> "Domain & Settings".
3. Add your URL to the whitelisted domains, e.g.: *.your-url.com